# Spring boot + JMS + IBM MQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I'm trying to send a message to a IBM MQ queue from my spring boot service. Configuration is as follows:

**Application.properties**

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1
ibm.mq.queue=DEV.QUEUE.1
ibm.mq.channel=DEV.APP.RECEIVER
ibm.mq.host=localhost
ibm.mq.port=1414
```

**ConectionFactory Bean**

```
@Bean
        public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            try {
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.ADMIN_QUEUE_DOMAIN);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
                mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
        }
```

**IBM MQ Explorer pictures**

**queue**
[image: queue]

**channel**
[image: channel]

**listener**
[image: listener]

When i try to send a message i get the error:

```
'2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2539' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR').
```

What i'm missing? The error sugest than my chammel type is not adecuate to my request, but i don't know waht does it means.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Client programs connect to SVRCONN channels, not RECEIVERs.

Answer (score 1):

It appears (as Mark mentioned) you are using the wrong channel type.  I quick google tells me that Spanish `Receptor` translates in English to `Receiver`.  A Receiver type channel is a Message channel and is used for queue manager to queue manager communication.

For MQ Client (ex: spring boot) to queue manager communication you need to connect to a MQI channel, on the queue manager this will have the type server connection.

---

The IBM MQ v8 Knowledge Center page "[IBM MQ Explorer>Configuring IBM MQ using MQ Explorer>Creating and configuring queue managers and objects>Objects in MQ Explorer>Channels](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_channels.htm)" documents this:

> **Message channel**
>   A message channel is a unidirectional communications link between two queue managers. IBM MQ uses message
>   channels to *transfer messages between the queue managers*. To send
>   messages in both directions, you must define a channel for each
>   direction.
>
> **MQI channel**
>   An MQI channel is bidirectional and *connects an application (MQI client) to a queue manager* on a server machine. IBM
>   MQ uses MQI channels to transfer MQI calls and responses between MQI
>   clients and queue managers.

IBM documents each type further down the page:

> **Message channels**
>
> Message channel definitions can be one of the following types:
>
> **Receiver**
>   A receiver channel is a message channel that the queue manager uses *to receive messages from other queue managers*. To receive
>   messages using a receiver channel, you must also create, on the other
>   queue manager, a sender or a server channel with the same name as this
>   receiver channel.

> **MQI channels**
>
> MQI channels can be one of the following types:
>
> **Server connection**
>   A server connection channel is a bidirectional MQI channel that is used to *connect an IBM MQ client to an IBM MQ
>   server*. The server connection channel is the server end of the
>   channel.